# Doubts regarding Pagerank execution

Tags: hadoop, pagerank

I'm trying to execute the code below : http://blog.xebia.com/2011/09/27/wiki-pagerank-with-hadoop/

The javac shows no errors, but I don't know how to get the output? These are the execution steps I'm following:

```
$ javac -Xlint -classpath /home/james/Downloads/hadoop-0.20.203.0/hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar -d  doc WikiPageRanking.java
$ jar -cvf WikiPageRanking.jar -C doc/ .
$ bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/james/wiki/in
$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal wiki-micro.txt /user/james/wiki/in
$ bin/hadoop jar WikiPageRanking.jar org.myorg.WikiPageRanking /user/james/wiki/in /user/james/wiki/result
```

Is this right? I seriously doubt the last step - the input and output paths!! In the code, they have used wiki/in, that's why I gave the same path here, and I have copied my sample dataset to this path. The map reduce process starts, but I get no output!!

Answer (score 0):

What does the following commands give you:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/james/wiki/result

hadoop fs -text /user/james/wiki/result/part*
```

Running a job does not automatically dump the results of the job to the console - they are most typically stored in HDFS (in your case in the path /user/james/wiki/result). You can view the contents of this directory using the first command, and assuming there are some part* files, the second command will dump their contents to disk

Final point to note - if the output format is SequenceFileOutputFormat and you're using custom key / value objects, you'll need to amend the second command to include your jar:

```
hadoop fs -libjars WikiPageRanking.jar -text /user/james/wiki/result/part*
```

Comment: It says no such file when I execute the first 2 commands, because I guess it is stored in hdfs, not local file system.

Comment: /user is typically the users home directory in HDFS (as opposed to /home in *nix) so you're looking at HDFS (unless your hadoop configuration has been configured to use the local filesystem as the default). Did your job actually succeed without error?

Comment: yes, the mapreduce tasks also completed, but the output file remains empty

Comment: how different is your implementation of WikiPageRanking to the original? https://github.com/abij/hadoop-wiki-pageranking/blob/master/src/com/xebia/sandbox/hadoop/WikiPageRanking.java - because this ignores command line args

Comment: Can you do a hadoop fs -ls /user/james/wiki/ranking for me?